# Use const foo = require(bar) in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, import, require

I wish to use this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitalets/google-translate-api" library in React but the the instructions say I need to "const translate = require('@vitalets/google-translate-api');". This doesn't work in React.

If I try import {translate} from "@vitalets/google-translate-api/index"; I get "Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically
extracted"

How can one use a library like this in React?

Answer (score 0):

[Google translate API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitalets/google-translate-api) is for node.js, meaning your backend

You're looking for [Google Translate Open API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-open-api) or [Translate Google Api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate-google-api) probably ? But the first package seems to be broken and they both seem to not be used/downloaded often

When you're downloading, make sure it can be used with ReactJS/js in general on the frontend